# How to place two DatagridView vertically in Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I would like to place two DataGridViews (Auto Binding ) vertically along with their labels in Winform. So it should fit with in area and look nice.

It should display on following order:
DataGridView Label1
DataGridView1
DataGridView Label2
DataGridView2

[image]

It should adjust Scroll and maximize behavior automatically. I have tried with Panels and FlowLayoutPanel but was not successful. I know how to do in WPF with relative layout, but no clue how to do in winform.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using the TableLayoutPanel control to house those DataGridView controls.

Comment: `Dock`? [From MSDN: Control.Dock Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.dock(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be mainly keeping the sizes of the two DGVs in synch.

For this you can use a `SplitContainer`, which will do that automatically:

- Set `Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal`
- Set `IsSplitterFixed = true`
- Set `FixedPanel` to `None`
- Set its `Anchors` to your liking, maybe to all four sides
- Put your two `DataGridViews` in the two `SplitContainer.Panels`
- The both DGVs to `Dock=Fill`

Now both DGVs will stay at the same size, sharing the `SplitContainer` size equally, or to be precise with the original ratio.

If you want `Labels` to sit above each DGV, simply put them in place but instad of `Dock=Fill` choose four `Anchors` for the DGVs.

If you want your `Buttons` to stay under the `SplitContainer` simple `Anchoring` will probably do..

Note that by nesting more such `SplitContainers` you can keep three or more `Controls` synched with the same sizes..

Comment: Your solution doesn't take into account the labels and whatever those navigation buttons are at the bottom.

Comment: That is true and the reason is that I don't know what he wants. Of course it is easily adapted once defined. Maybe with a second SplitContainer where the Buttons are in the lower part, which would then be the FixedPanel. I don't know where those Labels actually sit.. - But I have added a few remarks.

Comment: There are many solutions. Also it's better to put buttons in a panel and dock the panel to bottom, set labels to dock top and grids to dock fill. +1

Comment: Yes, many ways, but not many ways for automatically keeping two controls in synch. Putting the Buttons in a Panel semms a natural improvement..

Comment: @TaW thanks for your reply my requirement is not to take both DGVs at same size it should divide the space as per their dynamic size e.g DGV1 could have 50 rows and DGV2 could have just 5 rows. In this case I want both DGV should display, but most of the space should be occupied by DGV1. This ratio could vary dynamically as per individual rows..I don't know whether it's generic solution is possible??

Comment: Well you should have explained that more clearly. No, I don't think you can find an automatic solution. You will need to write code for the relevant events, depending on whether to DGVs are data-bound or not.. I assume by 'Auto-binding' you mean they are?

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter. You need to code a method, say `resizeSplitContainer` that calculates the new `splitContainer.SplitterDistance` and you call it in both `RowsAdded` events. I suggest to set `IsSplitterFixed = false` to let the user choose the sizes he actually needs!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using TableLayoutPanel control.
Created four rows:

Row1: SizeType:Absolute value:20

Row2:SizeType:AutoSize

Row3: SizeType:Absolute value:20
Row4:SizeType:AutoSize

And 
DatagridView1.AutoSize = true;
DatagridView2.AutoSize = true;

tableLayoutPanel1.AutoScroll=true;

Now, it adjust Scroll and maximize behavior automatically as per different size of DataGridViewRows

Thanks LarsTech and TaW and others for your support !!